# How to get a single data element from the database with Redux and React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I am new to React and Redux and am currently trying to fetch a single story (id, title, content, audio) from my database using the story ID. I have set up the component, the action and the reducer.

However i run into the following error, occuring in the component:

**Cannot read property 'then' of undefined**

```
getStory(id) {
> 31 |    this.props.getSingleStory(id)
     | ^  32 |      .then(response => {
  33 |        this.setState({
  34 |          story: response.data
```

**Story Detail Component**

```
import {getSingleStory } from '../../actions/story';
....

export class StoryDetails extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getStory = this.getStory.bind(this);

    this.state = {
    story: {
        id: null,
        title: "",
        content: "",
        audio: ""
      }

    };
}
    componentDidMount() {
    this.getStory(this.props.match.params.id);
  }

  getStory(id) {
    this.props.getSingleStory(id)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          story: response.data
        });
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }  

render() {

    const { story } = this.state;
    return (

  <Fragment>

        <h2>Stories</h2>

            {story.title}
            {story.content}
      </Fragment>

    );
  }
}



const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  story: state.story.story

});




export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getSingleStory}
)(StoryDetails);
```

**Action** (The action is registered in types)

```
// GET SINGLE STORY
export const getSingleStory = id => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .get( apiBase + `/story/${id}/`, tokenConfig(getState))
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_SINGLE_STORY,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
  .catch(err =>
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    );
};
```

**Reducer**

```
    case GET_SINGLE_STORY:
      return {
        ...state,
        story: state.story.filter(story => story.id !== action.payload)
      };
```

As far as I can see, my GET_SINGLE_STORY action returns 'res.data'. So I can't figure out why 'then' is undefined.

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: are you using thunk as a middleware, since your function is async ?  Not sure your mapDispatchToProps is currently set...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return a promise in your getSingleStory (You return nothing)

```
export const getSingleStory = id => (dispatch, getState) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get( apiBase + `/story/${id}/`, tokenConfig(getState))
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_SINGLE_STORY,
                payload: res.data
            });
            resolve(res);
         })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
            reject(err);
        });
   });
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works but i dont understand why. What is Promise doing in the concrete case? Why is my getSingleStoryaction not returning anything without the promise?

Comment: axios call return a promise (because it's async). if in your getSingleStory method you just return axios(...) then in getStory you can use then and catch, but you use axios then and catch in your getSingleStory, and you return nothing to caller (getStory), and then you try to use then and catch of (nothing), I returned a new promise to resolve and reject in axios promise then and catch, now your caller (getStory) can wait for axios request to complete or error.